# Find the intervals where $f(x)$ is decreasing

Tags: calculus

How can I find the intervals where $f(x)=x^3-\frac{3}{2}x^2$ is decreasing? I have found that $f'(x)=3x^2-3x$. The critical values are at $0$ and $1$.

This is what I did so far, but they're increasing and in zero:

```
-1 E (-∞,0), f'(-1)= 3(-1)²-3(-1)  = 6 > 0
0 E (0,1)  , f'(0)=  3(0)² -3(0)   = 0
2 E (1,∞)  , f'(2)=  3(2)² -3(2)   = 6 > 0
```

Comment: Hi Ruby, and welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange. Your mistake is that the critical values are not when $f(x)=0$, but when $f'(x)=0$. Since $f'(x)=6x-3$ (using the power rule), there is a single point at which the function goes from being decreasing to increasing. It also helps to think about the problem geometrically. Every parabola has a vertex where it goes from increasing to decreasing, or vice versa. Try plotting the graph of $f$ to see what I mean.

Comment: Also, are you asking where $f$ is decreasing, or where $f'$ is decreasing? Since $f'$ is a linear function with positive gradient, it is increasing everywhere. Presumably you are asking about when $f$ is decreasing.

Comment: Hi, I'm sorry that was my mistake there. Thanks for reminding me, above is already the first derivative, as: f(x)=x^3-3/2x². Therefore, f'(x)= 3x²-3x @Joe

Comment: I've edited your post. Do I understand your question correctly now?

Comment: Yes, thank you so much!! @Joe

Comment: I deleted my last comment because it is mistaken. Your function is decreasing in some places and increasing in others. I will post a fuller answer soon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $f'(x)=3x^2-3x$, the graph of $f’$ is a U-shaped parabola with roots at $0$ and $1$. Hence, $f'(x)<0$ whenever $0<x<1$:

[image: Parabola graph]

The mistake you made was that you plugged in $0$ into $f'(x)=3x^2-3x$. This gives us a turning point of the cubic. If you plug in a value of $x$ that is between $0$ and $1$ *exclusive*, then you will find that $f'(x)<0$.

Answer (score 3):

The critical points are the $x$ values such that $f'(x)=0$. You must find these, then check the sign of $f'(x)$ in each interval formed by "slicing" the real number line at the critical points. For example, if you find the critical points to be $x=-2$ and $x=7$, then you must check the sign of $f'(x)$ for $x \in (-\infty,-2)$, for $x \in (-2,7)$ and for $x \in (7,\infty)$. The original function $f$ is increasing on the intervals for which $f'(x)>0$, and decreasing on the intervals for which $f'(x)<0.$ You should think about what the derivative represents graphically and why this process makes sense.